# Implementing a Gaussian-based loss function in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement my custom loss function in Keras using TensorFlow backend. The idea is for the neural network to input coefficients for Gaussians and compare the sum of four Gaussians to the model output. So we're fitting Gaussians to the data. I'd like to have y_pred in the form of [a_0, b_0, c_0, a_1, ..., c_3] and calculate the sum of a_i*e^((x-b_i)^2/2c_i), i=0,1,2,3 and then work out for example mean absolute error comparing this function to y_true. What I tried was

```
def gauss_loss(y_true, y_pred):
   # zs is the the size y_true
   # the size of y_pred is 12
   xs = np.linspace(0, 1, zs)
   gauss_sum = 0
   for i in range(0, 12, 3):
        gauss_sum += y_pred[:,i]*K.exp(-(xs-y_pred[:,i+1])**2/(2*y_pred[:,i+2]))
   return 1./zs*sum(K.abs(y_true-gauss_sum))
```

I get the error "TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn".

However, I don't think I can use tf.map_fn either because it only accepts one argument so I can't use the first entry of y_pred as coefficient *a* and the next as *b* in the same formula.

All examples I find just use tensor operations for the entire matrix. It seems to me that this might not even be possible in Keras. Is this possible and if so, how is it done?

Comment: Doesn't `xs` need an index in that expression too?

Comment: @DanielMöller The idea is that both gauss_sum and y_true are the same size so I can subtract them from each other in the last line.

Comment: Those shapes are not quite compatible, how do you expect the result of `xs - y_pred[:,i+1]`, considering their shapes are `(12,)` and `(batch_size,)`?.  Depending on your answer, different techniques must be used.